# Migrating the build.gradle to build.gradle.Kts : Not able to resolve Properties class

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

While converting the `build.gradle` to `build.gradle.kts` is a manual process, I'm struggling in conversion in the below piece of code.

I tried with invalidating the cache and restarting the studio many times. However, android.varinatFilter is not recognized.

```
android.variantFilter { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == 'release'
            && variant.getFlavors().get(0).name == 'development') {
        variant.setIgnore(true)
    }
    if (variant.buildType.name == 'debug'
            && variant.getFlavors().get(0).name == 'production') {
        variant.setIgnore(true)
    }
}
```

Properties class of `Java.util.Properties` dependency doesn't get resolved in `.kts` file also the FileInputStream class of `Java.io` is not recognized.

```
 def getProps(path) {
        Properties props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(file(path)))
        return props
    }
```

Also while applying the kotlin annotation processor

```
kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.1.0' To

kapt {'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.1.0'}
```

doesn't work and returns compile-time error.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

> Properties class of `Java.util.Properties` dependency doesn't get resolved in `.kts` file also the FileInputStream class of `Java.io` is not recognized.

This will get resolved with Invalidate cache and Restart.(Start refactoring project level gradle then settings.gradle and then app.gradle file in sequence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `kapt {'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.1.0'}` - please use double quotes, e.g. `kapt {"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.1.0"}`, please [check details here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html).

Please also use the following syntax for method:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.Properties

/***/

fun getProps(path: String): Properties {
    val props = Properties()
    props.load(FileInputStream(file(path)))
    return props
}
```

Changes:

- You need imports with java packages at the beginning of the file.
- Use `fun` instead of `def`
- Parameter types are required for methods, use ':' for this - `path: String`
- `new` keyword is not needed
- [Variable declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) can started with `val`, e.g. if compiler is able to understand the type, you don't need to enter it manually.
- [Return type is mandatory](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html) if your result is not `Unit`.

For filter - I didn't worked with this. However please consider:

- Replacing quotes ' to "
- Replacing `variant.getFlavors().get(0).name` to `variant.flavors[0].name`
- Replacing `variant.setIgnore(true)` to `variant.ignore=true`

Comment: Both of this `import java.io.FileInputStream`, `import java.util.Properties` doesn't get resolved.

Comment: @Dipalis., it is IntelliJ Idea error or the same line is appeared after execution ```gradlew``` at the command line?

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```kotlin
android.variantFilter {
    if (buildType.name == "release" && flavors[0].name == "development") {
        ignore = true
    }
    if (buildType.name == "debug" && flavors[0].name == "production") {
        ignore = true
    }
}
```

although I think that a more correct approach for

```kotlin
flavors[0].name = "xyz"
```

should be

```kotlin
flavors.map { it.name }.contains("xyz")
```